# Is each shard of mongodb invisible to other shards in one cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm curious about the "dependency structure" of each role in a mongodb cluster.

I know the `config` server knows all the `shard` servers, and the `mongos` server get all the information from the `config` server, but:

1. Do the `shard` servers know about the `config` server?
2. Does one `shard` server know about other `shard` servers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess for both questions the answer is "yes". Otherwise balancing would not be possible, see [Sharded Cluster Balancer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/)

For sure the related ports needs to be open in your firewalls, otherwise the sharded cluster does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! According to [Chunk Migration Procedure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/#chunk-migration-procedure), one shard should know the other shard and the config server, but I didn't find them in the `config` or `local` database. Maybe these informations are only in memory and only kept in one moveChunk command execution?

Comment: There is a collection `config.cache.databases` which holds documents for `admin` and `config`. But apart from that it seems to be hold only in memory.

Comment: Yes I can see the documents in collection `config.cache.databases` but there is no server address/port info.